# Tuple of primitive generic type as generic function return

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to understand which factors are at play in the following example.

I have the following types.

```
type Primitive = string | number | bigint | boolean | symbol | null | undefined

type A<T> = T extends Primitive ? [T] :never; // put T as tuple member if T primitive
```

When I want to use them to type function arguments I cannot understand some of the narrowing that is either happening or not happening.

For the following function

**example A**

```
const a = <T extends Primitive>(a:A<T>)=>a[0]
a(['a string']) //string | number | bigint | boolean | symbol | null | undefined
```

Calling the function with a string returns a union of all generics.

If I have a similar function but on that does not attempt to index the tuple but returns it, then I get the expected type:

**example B**

```
const b = <T extends Primitive>(a:A<T>)=>a
b(['a string']) // [string] (['a string'])
```

And if I have yet another similar function, but one that does not impose the Primitive constraint on the generic, then I also get the expected result whilst still indexing the result:

**example C**

```
const c = <T extends unknown>(a:A<T>)=>a[0]
c(['a string']) //string (['a string'])
```

I would essentially like to be able to both have the ability to index the argument and get the actual type within the function as well as impose the Primitive constraint.
I have some idea that the cause is likely to do with the way type A is defined and perhaps the tuple/array needs to be defined in a stricter way.

I guess theoretically what I would like to understand is why example C works but A does not. My feeling is that it is because the array (intended tuple) is expecting the type to be primitive array so at the time the values are returned the type is purposefully vague. This explains why spreading the array like `const a = <T extends Primitive>(a:A<T>)=>[...a][0]` does not show the same issue.

Here's a link to [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBACgTgSwLYOAgbtAvFAzsRAOwHMoAfKQgVyQCMI5ypaFiFDgnaB7bgGwgBDQk1wg6-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-P6Ao7OyFukgehE+0jPIyBrS05T8PjcGXCsDrQRIXW4LT5ziCOn1iNtB6dWbPYCCMuDAJGAA0sUEIDnggUHa+PzAt-vCgBQO3zzBJ7PwDBa9wQHaFh2iUcpBoegMWYVgi1xfghBEQlxB4ElKDJdD5CUVRggUIA)

Comment: Not sure why and how you want to deal with `T extends unknown` case, but for the first one this should work as expected: `const a = <const T extends readonly Primitive[]>(a: T): T[0]`. Let me know if does work for you so I can write an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: Thanks, I don't care about using unknown, in fact I don't want to use it. I added to show somehow it works without the constraint.

Comment: I would like to keep the generic as is. Consider the following `const a2 = <T extends Primitive>(target:T, payload:A<T>)=>payload[0]`. Could add second generic based off first but would like to understand what the behaviour is also.

Comment: If you will use generic just for the single element you won't be able to retrieve the exact type of the first element, since `T` is going to be a union

Comment: If I define function `a` like `const a = <T extends Primitive>(t:T, a:A<T>)=>[...a][0]` then I get desired result. So I guess it's just about uncertainty that array can change so creating new array ensures that at that time its the exact type

Comment: you can drop `extends unknown` (unary generic with tsx on is `<T,>` with ',')

Comment: `const c = <T,>(a: A<T> & [Primitive]) => a[0]` would work, `const c = <T,>(a: A<T>) => a[0]` works if your `A<T>` is checked inside

Comment: Can you not add a return type to your function? `const a = <T extends Primitive>(a:A<T>): A<T>[0] => a[0];`

Comment: Can you [edit] to clarify the specific question you're asking?  Preferably phrased as a question?  Right now it looks like you want to know "the factors at play" in an example, which seems really broad.  Or maybe you're asking for a way to do something, in which case you might want to make it very explicit.  Also, is there a reason you want `A<T>` instead of just `[T]` (especially if `T extends Primitive`), as shown [here](//tsplay.dev/NVl7BW)?  Conditional types and inference can be weird, and I want to make sure you're doing it for a good reason before trying to drill into explanations.

Comment: I've updated the question with a brief paragraph that can be used as the main question. I'd say the reason I kept it on the vague side was because I wanted to understand the weirdness you mention. As for the `A<T> rather than `[T]` it would because `never` is just for the minimal reproducible example but it should be something else in the context of the rest of the code.

Comment: So the question is "Why does `c` work while `a` does not?", right?  Could you set that apart and make it obvious from a cursory glance that *that* is the question, and that (presumably) you're not interested in alternative approaches?  Then people who want to answer can focus on the question at hand.  (Unfortunately I have no idea why they are behaving differently, and unless I can find a relevant GitHub issue, the only way I'd know is if someone files such an issue and it gets an official answer.)